# How to connect to android internal localhost

Tags: java, android

I am to programming so please help me in some issues.

I download app from Google play that filter web searches. If URL in blacklist then redirect to this webpage `localhost:50099/block.html`

My query is how to connect this local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the app you are running has its own internal web-server. If you see that address in the navigation address bar of the app you are running then you may not be able to access it outside of the app.

Are you browsing the web from inside the app itself?  What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to access an internal web-server running on an android device which is open to other apps, then you should be able to access it using the URL you noted.  I have seen light weight web-servers internal to apps in both conditions, only accessible internally within the app and accessible outside of the app.

**UPDATE: Since your question is now 'How to create a lightweight HTTP server on Android':**

Try this: [HTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)

It is very simple to use, eg:

```
NanoHTTPD serverObj = new NanoHTTPD(50099,new File("."));
```

Comment: I access this localhost url from chrome and from native browser.

Comment: please suggest me any link to create internal web server programmatically in android.

Comment: Thanx @thrill for help I solve problem with the help of you.

Answer (score 0):

use IP address of your machine instead of localost in url eg :-

http://192.168.1.190:50099/block.html

Comment: there is no pc/laptop. it's remotely access this localhost url. I think its own internal web-server within android device